# NullPointerException will be thrown on method call

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

I have a simple method:

```
public String getValue(String tag)    {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(tag))    {
        return null;
    }

    return tag.substring(tag.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).trim();
}
```

Which is then called later on like this:

```
String tag = node.getNodeValue(); <-- from org.w3c.dom.Node
String value = getValue(tag);

String price = getAttribute(param1, param2, getValue(value));
```

SonarQube is warning me about a NullPointerException:

> "NullPointerException" will be thrown when invoking method "getValue()" <-- the second call

However, I fail to see how. The method by itself is null-proof. What is happening ? Is SonarQube unable to go down the `StringUtils.isBlank` method ? Or is it the `getAttribute()` method that will give me the NullPointerException, and the error message can seem misleading ?

Comment: are you sure is not getAttribute that will generate the NPE? probably is warning you that the call to getValue can return null, and getAttribute will throw with that null value returned by getValue

Comment: Well, that is one of my questions: I quite don't know :(

Comment: Well, check the getAttribute function, or post it here

Comment: I know this isn't part of the question, but you have a logical error in your code. The line `String price = getAttribute(param1, param2, getValue(value));` should be `String price = getAttribute(param1, param2, value);`. While your code will work, it is doing more than it needs to. Lets say tag="foo/bar" then value will be "bar" after the call to get value in the second line. Then when you are getting price you are calling getValue("bar"), which will return "bar", but why waste the computer's time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this warning because of the following line:

```
return null;
```

Why would you return `null` when `tag` is blank? I suggest you do it as:

```
return tag;
```

or maybe

```
return "";
```

However, your function will still remain prone to `NullPointerException` because `tag` may be `null`. To avoid the possibility of `NullPointerException`, I suggest the following implementation for your function:

```
public String getValue(String tag) {
    if (tag != null) {
        tag = tag.substring(tag.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).trim();
    }

    return tag;
}
```

Comment: they are not equivalent, if tag="           " then returning null or "           "  are not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

If the string is null, you can´t invoke any method on it.

The trim method will trigger the null pointer exception:

```
 return tag.substring(tag.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).trim();
```

Consider using an Optional for the string: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html